# JSTREE What is data.reference?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have recently started using jstree and found some online examples. However, I don't quite understand what is data.reference and I cannot find any documentation on it.

```
             action": function (data) {
                    var ref = $.jstree.reference(data.reference);
                sel = ref.get_node(data.reference);
                var parentChildren = sel.children;
                sel = ref.create_node(sel, { type: "category","text": "New Category","li_attr":{"label":"New Category","description":"","detail":""}}, 'first');

                ref.move_node(parentChildren, sel);

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the data is actually an object `{}` which has a key named `reference`:

```
function (data) { // { reference: "refValue/anotherobject/array"}
    var ref = $.jstree.reference(data.reference);
```

---

<sup>*You can use `debugger;` to stop the process at this point and you can see the response in the inspector tool of your browser.*</sup>